# What kinds of effects can modify a die roll?

Tags: dnd-4e

After you roll a d20, there are some effects that can modify the result before the calculation is made. Is this a complete list?

- If you don't like the roll (before you know success or failure), throw it away and roll it again
- If you don't like the roll (after you know the result), throw it away and roll it again
- Roll it again and take the better result (oath of enmity)
- Roll it again and take the worse result (various curses)
- replace a die roll with one you rolled before (dice of auspicious fortune)
- add a number to the die roll (heroic effort, adept's insight)

And I think these only apply to a damage roll:

- Brutal

  - if it's N or below, re-roll until it's N+1 or above
- if it's N or below, throw away the old roll and re-roll once, taking the result no matter what
- if it's N or below, change to N+1
- if it's the maximum value, roll again once and take the sum
- if it's the maximum value, roll again, take the sum, and repeat if it's maximum value (vorpal/explosive)

Comment: * Event: Someone dumps the pizza box on top of the dice and the board, scattering everything everywhere.

Comment: Nitpick: With the dice of auspicious fortune, you use the result you rolled earlier *instead* of rolling the attack, not after you see it and dislike it. So it doesn't exactly fit in this list (since you're not modifying the result, you're predetermining it).

Comment: suggestion: take all of those out and put them in a single comprehensive CW answer

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Just trying to have a complete list in one place of all the die-modification effects. It is not based on an actual problem that I am currently experiencing other than "I'm not sure my knowledge is complete". Now that I've re-read the FAQ it seems to not fit the criteria for inclusion here. It does seem more suited for CW, but hasn't that been discontinued? I don't see how to get to it anymore.

Comment: @Snowbody my suggestion is a bit different than CWing the question. My proposal is to create one single *answer* as CW it and maintain it as a list of all possible ways to modify the roll. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you count these into one or more of your bullet points, but...

- Add another die roll to the die roll ([Memory of a Thousand Lifetimes](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=6186)<sup>[DDI]</sup>).
- Replace the die roll with a fixed number ([Climatic Crescendo](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=14495)<sup>[DDI]</sup>, if you consider the critical hit a natural 20, which could be a bit over-reading it).

Answer (score 1):

Brutal N is re-roll until you get N+1.

Certain features allow you to a roll a d20 ahead of time and save it, then replace a later roll with the result of the saved roll if you want.

Comment: Correct, but these are cases already covered by the Questioner.